# Best practice to pass complex JS object to bind on server-side model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC5 and I don't know what is the best practice to deal with this type of situation :

Let's imagine a webpage with a map. When the user clicks a button, the bounds of the map are sent to a server-side action

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MapBoundsModel model)
{
    //some stuff
}
```

Here, `MapBoundsModel` is an object containing the bounds of the map, **but it's build with Javascript**

So here is what I do :

```
//Create a JS object which is similar to my server-side model
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.Center = myMap.getCenter();
//and all the opther properties of the server-side object

//Call my server-side action with an Ajax call
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ mapBoundsModel : myObject})
})
```

And my server side controller looks like that

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MapBoundsModel mapBoundsModel)
{
    //doWork
}
```

This works, but it seems ugly to me because if I change my `MapBoundsModel` by adding or removing a property, the JS object will not have the new / removed property and this will produce unexpected result at run-time (and VS will let me compile it)

I guess one can do it with tons of hidden fields into a strongly-typed view, but this doesn't look like very clean to me.

So, is there any best practice to pass a "copy" of a **complex** server-side model from JS ?
I'm open to a solution implying any VS plugin if it exists

Comment: You can pass an instance of `MapBoundsModel` to the view and use `var myObject = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` to serialize it to a javascipt object.

Comment: But then, how can I "construct"  my `MapBoundsModel` ? I have no choice but calling a JS method to get the bounds, so how can I bind the results (the bounds) to the `Model` send to the server ?  
Except using hidden fields ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You asked how to create a javascript object that matches the property names in a server side model (I have no idea how your setting the values of those properties)

Comment: To sum up, I'd like to know if there is a best way to "link" a JS object to a server side model ? So, if I had to change my server-side model, I'd like to get notified that I have to change my JS object (like a compilation error or a VS plugin who can "see" the needed change or something...)

Comment: I see. Javascript and c# are separate languages running in separate environments so short answer is no.